# EKS with ALB infront of internal Nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

We are running internet-facing ALB with WAF as the gateway into our private EKS cluster.
All routes in the ALB pointing to nginx-ingress-controller-internal service:

```
paths:
          - path: {{ $.Values.ingressExternal.path }}
            pathType: {{ $.Values.ingressExternal.pathType }}
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-ingress-controller-internal
                port:
                  name: http
```

We have an internal nginx-ingress-controller with NodePort service type that should route the requests into the backend services.

The issue is that the internal nginx can't find the backend services and all requests are reaching default backend service with 404.

Any advice on what is missing in the config?

Best,

We try:

- to use ClusterIP in the internal nginx service
- run all ingress in the same namespace as the backend services
- change the pathType